# Displaying image with package multicols?

Tags: multicol

I am having an issue doing as the title says.  I did

```
\usepackage{multicols}
...
\begin{multicols}{2}
...
\begin{figure}[!h]
\center
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{IMAGE} 
\caption{CAPTION}
\end{figure} 
...
\end{multicols}
```

When I do this, no image appears.  I tried changing the scale, but still no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use a `figure` float. Instead, add the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and use `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}`.

Comment: You should use ``centering`, not `\center`. Is the image  supposed to use the whole text width, or only one column width?

Comment: `\usepackage{multicols}` generates `! LaTeX Error: File 'multicols.sty' not found.`  You presumably? intended `multicol` If you load `multicol` the terminal output seems fairly clear: `Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside 'multicols' 
environment!.`